# GNU Compiler: Procedure entry point ...could not be located - after g++ upgrade

Tags: c++, windows, g++, cygwin, dllimport

I'm using **g++** with **cygwin** on a **Win PC** to compile an application and (static) link a 3rd party dll that was compiled using a microsoft compiler and that I cannot recompile and that is always the same.

This worked fine for the old system, then we ported it to a new PC

**Old**: Win  7 64, cygwin and g++ vers **6.4**

**New**: Win 10 64, cygwin and g++ vers **10.2**

Now I get the runtime problem "the Procedure entry point ... could not be located" error for standard functions as e.g. __assert_func.

Checking with Dependencies (former Dependency Walker) I found that these functions are now searched in the cygwin1.dll **and** in the 3rd party dll.
Searching in cygwin1.dll is correct, since this is the cygwin dll to provide all these functions.
But I wonder why the application also assumes that they could be found in this 3rd party dll that doesn't provide them but also the functions I would expect.

This is also reflected in the Dependencies report: Functions are found in cygwin1.dll but not in the 3rd party dll.

I could track it down, that it's only related to the g++ version used to build, doesn't matter on which PC I run the application.

Any idea what could be the reason?

I experimented with the -fabi-version option to use the abi-version that was used with gcc 6.4 but this also didn't help

Regards
Klaus

Comment: `__assert_func` is available from `cygwin1.dll` . Please show the command causing the roors. May be it is just a matter of proper libraries order

Comment: It's not a specific command that causes the problem, it's a question of linking against the 3rd party lib or not. I made a simple project with a "hello world" main.cpp using one function of the lib (EtIpScanner) and build with

g++ -o main.exe main.cpp -I . -L . -lEtIPScanner

If I don't use assert, the next function that causes a procedure entry point problem at runtime is __cxa_atexit because it's alphabetically the next one needed. 

Dependencies shows that also malloc, cmalloc, free and others are searched and found in cygwin1.dll but also searched and not found in the 3rd party dll.

Comment: to link anything a `command` is needed. How is the linker called ?  Please show the full command line causing the error

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me, but I'm afraid that 

`g++ -o main.exe main.cpp -I . -L . -lEtIPScanner`

is the full command line except running the app

`main.exe`

g++ also runs the linker.
I could split it in two commands 

`gcc -c main.c` and `ld -o main.exe main.o -L . -lEtIpScanner -L /bin -lcygwin1`

In this example it's for C instead of C++ and I have to add the cygwin1 manually, but this doesn't change the basic problem of standard functions being searched additionally in a wrong dll if the dll was compiled with Microsoft and the gnu compiler was updated from 6.4 to 10.2